# Installing setup tools for python

Tags: python

I'm trying to install setuptools on centos 5.6 for python 2.7.1. The system version is python 2.4

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390558/installing-setuptools-in-a-private-version-of-python) but the solution still brings up the same error: `setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg: line 3: exec: python2.7: not found`

Python is located in `/usr/bin/python2.7.1`

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get your point. Are you trying to install setuptools for python 2.7.1 while you have python 2.4 installed? Then it is obvious you should upgrade python before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the installer wants to execute `python2.7`, whereas your binary is called `python2.7.1`.

Try making a symlink in your `/usr/bin/` directory.

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7.1 /usr/bin/python2.7`

Comment: Ah thank you! I should have notice that!

Now when I run `sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg` I get the error `zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available` but in a python interpretor `import zlib` works just fine

Comment: Got a different zlib install and recompiled python and got it working. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows.
In C:\ncrdev\Python27, I copied python.exe to python2.7.exe and that fixed it too.